# Question vs Presentation

Tags: discussion

Fresh off the current close list is a question about a [US watch list](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/49080/why-is-pakistan-in-the-us-watch-list-of-religious-freedom-while-india-is-not) of religious freedom.

Now the question clearly had a position to push, the length surrounding detail section made it quite clear what that position was.

But the title sounded like a reasonable question that may be answerable with public sources  namely what factors warrant inclusion on this list and if it is based on a simple score or a judgement call somewhere.

Can anything be done to save this question?

Comment: We certainly could save the question by doing the things you mention, but should we? If someone writes a biased push question, should we really put in effort to save the question, thus giving them unearned rep and privileges, and/or putting them in the position of managing a question they didn’t really want to ask? If they just wanted to say, for example, that person X is evil, then do we really gain anything from changing their question to be about something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone can ask a new question on more neutral terms, e.g. what is publicly known about how the US list in question is determined. It's probably a better solution than deleting 95% of the body of a push question...

Also, even if we delete the push part, the question as asked is probably mainly asking for speculation. In fact, the (negatively voted) answer is mostly focusing on that (i.e. speculation).

(The question also ignored [the fact that Modi was banned](https://tif.ssrc.org/2014/05/15/the-complicated-case-of-narendra-modis-visa/) for from entering the US based on the same Act, in the past. Also India [was on the watch list](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/us-body-puts-india-under-watch-list-on-religious-freedom/articleshow/4888730.cms) before. Also, the commission has [expressed](https://www.christianpost.com/news/uscirf-fears-india-creating-religious-test-for-citizenship-as-protests-against-bill-erupt.html) concerns about the recent developments in India, and has even recommended [new] sanctions.)